# Android Camera2: How to use SENSOR_BLACK_LEVEL_PATTERN API?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop, android-camera2

In `Camera2`, I found one API called [SENSOR_BLACK_LEVEL_PATTERN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_BLACK_LEVEL_PATTERN). I am trying to get information of my device related to this API. Somehow I don't understand how to get it. I have done it upto here:

```
CameraCharacteristics mCameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

BlackLevelPattern blackLevelPattern = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_BLACK_LEVEL_PATTERN);

//What to do next with  blackLevelPattern?
```

Want to use `getOffsetForIndex()` method.

**UPDATE:**
Is this fine to use like this: `blackLevelPattern.getOffsetForIndex(0, 0)`

Please suggest. thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual question? What do you want to use it for? The BlackLevelPattern object isn't terrible multifaceted, you've really already noted its only interesting method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to do it using below code:

```
CameraCharacteristics mCameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);                                
BlackLevelPattern blackLevelPattern = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_BLACK_LEVEL_PATTERN);
                                int[][] array = new int[2][2];
                                for (int c = 0; c < array.length; c++) {
                                    for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {
                                        append(blackLevelPattern.getOffsetForIndex(c, r);

                                        }
                                    }
```